# list directory sizes and compress them

Tags: tar, disk-usage, compression, size

I have a list of directories I want to compress on an ubuntu machine.

Is there any tool to automatically calculate the size of the of my folders and copy the size to the name of the compressed file?

I have some thing like that:

```
$du -h -d 1
671G    ./folder1
2.7T    ./folder2
```

I would like it to be like this

```
$ls -1 
folder1.671.G.tar.gz
folder2.2.7T.tar.gz
```

The given sizes with the `du -h -d 1` are the non-compressed one, so the size calculation needs to happen after the compression.

Thanks

Comment: Why do you want the compressed size in the file name? You can easily see the compressed size of the archive with `du -h` at any time. The uncompressed size (which would result from unpacking the archive) is IMHO a much more useful information.

Answer (score 0):

```
for folder in $(ls -l | grep ^d | awk '{print $NF}'); do
  tar zcf ${folder}.tar.gz ${folder}
  size=$(du -sh ${folder}.tar.gz | awk '{print $1}')
  mv ${folder}.tar.gz ${folder}-${size}.tar.gz
done
```

- Tar & zip all folders in the current directory
- Get the size of the tar file
- Rename the tar file to include the size

Comment: see why `for folder in $(ls...` is wrong: https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_f_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29

Comment: better use `find . -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -type d | sed 's#^\./##' | while IFS= read -r folder ; do`... and quote all occurrences of `${folder}` as `"$folder"` or `"${folder}"` or e.g. `"${folder}.tar.gz"` etc.

Comment: [Why *not* parse `ls`?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls)